# How to register a use with role in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I wants to create a new user with role. I'm using entity migration. so i get the all default tables. Without roles I'm able to register a new user but when i add the roles drop down I'm facing a error Cannot convert from string to ourproject.entitites.user

Please help and teach me where i did the mistake. I'm new to .net core technology.

I'm facing a problem with user.Id

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
```

ControllerCode:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterUserModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new User { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email,
                    PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
                //var phoneNo = new User { PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
                var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (createResult.Succeeded)
                {                    
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home");                    
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_Context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin"))
                                          .ToList(), "Name", "Name");
                    foreach (var error in createResult.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Registermodel Code:

```
 public class RegisterUserModel
    {
        [Required,MaxLength(256)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password), Compare(nameof(Password))]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress),MaxLength(256)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required,DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="UserRoles")]
        public string UserRoles { get; set; }

    }
```

User Entity Code:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

```
namespace OurProject.Entities
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional code for .net core 2.0. In AddToRoleAsync method I am sending user object itself.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string roleName = "Manager";
                var isExistRole = await this._roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);

                if (!isExistRole)
                {
                    await this._roleManager.CreateAsync(                            
                        new IdentityRole
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Name = roleName
                    });
                }

                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Tq for your reply.

Comment: Hi! Tq for your reply. Mr. Mizanur Rahman Sarker

Actually, a user wants to choose the role without any hardcoded. So, in that case, I've created a drop down from AspNetRoles table. using that drop down values I have to insert the user id and role id in AspNetUserRoles table. 
I did a small change in my controller code 

await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles) to 
var details = new User { UserName = user.Id };
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(details, model.UserRoles);

please help me how to finish this task.

Comment: Now i'm facing a new error.

InvalidOperationException: User security stamp cannot be null.

Comment: Finally got the solution.
'await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.UserRoles);'
after changing the ACCOUNTCONTROLLER I'm able to create a user with role.

Comment: Hi, how u fix "User security stamp cannot be null" finally ? i create user with  "await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "123456");" and then add role with "await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");" but got same error